# Triple integration $x=0$, $x=3$, $y=0$, $y=3 x²+y²=18-z$, $z=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Given
\begin{align}
x&=0, \hspace{10mm} x=3 \\
y&=0, \hspace{10mm} y=3 \\
x^2+y^2&=18-z, \: z=0
\end{align}
Find the volume using triple integrals

I'm not sure how to choose my bounds, however I can solve this problem using double integrals and integrating $\int _0^3\int _0^3\left(18-x²-y²\right) \,dxdy$,
but I want to solve this problem using triple integrals.

How can I choose my bounds such that the volume can be found using triple integrals?

Comment: Integral with respect to $z$ can be written for  bounds between $0$ and $18-x^2-y^2$ i.e. $\int\limits_{0}^{18-x^2-y^2}dz=18-x^2-y^2$

Comment: [This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420206/28900) is similar.

Comment: Thank you zkutch, didn't really think of that at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Okay, so we want to find the area of this shape here. To find the bounds, we need to rewrite everything in terms of "x=", "y=", and "z=". Hence,

$$x=0, x=3$$
$$y=0, y=3$$
$$z=0, z=-(x^2+y^2-18)$$

Our triple integral then is just
$$\int_0^3\int_0^3\int_0^{18-x^2-y^2}  dzdydx=\int_0^3\int_0^3 18 - x^2 - y^2dydx=\int_0^3 45 - 3 x^2dx=108$$

(as a minor side note even though the x^2 and y^2 makes it tempting to swap to other coordinates, rectangular coordinates are easy enough lol)